# Support following users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I suggest that users be able to follow other users so they can see useful, and or fun things that user posts.

Answer (score 6):

This has been asked about before over on the [StackExchange Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) (which is the place for network wide feature requests, though I didn't migrate there as it is already a duplicate.)

You can take a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice) and answer about how to follow the posts of a user using RSS.  Additionally, you can favorite "[tags](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tags)" which are different categories of questions that you want to follow.